# Communicating locally through WiFi while simultaneously maintaining internet connection through cellular in a web application

Tags: javascript, webrtc, p2p, web-frontend

I would like to set up the following: Alice and Bob should be connected on the internet through their cellular\independent main connections while communicating internally (LAN Router or Directly but **not through the internet**) in a web application. The environment is a web browser, such as Chrome.

For example, if a file has two parts 1 and 2, Alice downloads part 1 and share it upon completion to Bob. At the same time, Bob does the same for part 2 and shares it with Alice. The main point is that they collaboratively download the file without losing on their data plan by downloading it through their main connection.

Is there a way through client-side Javascript or a protocol that allows this behavior on the browser? I am looking at WebRTC but there's no way to control the path that the messages sent through the data channel takes from the browser.

Thank you!

Asaad

Comment: you're likely looking for webtorrent.io which is a variant of bittorrent that runs ontop of webrtc

Answer (score 2):

WebRTC does allow you to choose the path somewhat, you can exclude candidates you don't want to use when signaling.

When you are exchanging ICE candidates you can filter out any ones you don't want. By default if you don't include a STUN/TURN server in your iceServers list it will always be P2P in your LAN. During the gathering process the agent (browser) will only know about host candidates.

Comment: How can I ensure that the communication with other peers are not done through cellular\internet enabled network but through the WiFi network that has no internet which all peers will be connected to?